# How can I break up a column from one table with a delimiter into multiple columns in a new table?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I am a self-taught PL/SQL query writer who is relatively new to coding. I know how to conduct basic functions, but have had no formal training and usually google my way to solve any issues I come across. The majority of the time, I am just joining different tables or views in PL/SQL developer to make

I am trying to break up a line from a table based on a series of three delimiters, in this case " > " (spaces included). For example, I want to pull the location "USA > California > Los Angeles" from a table called Locations and break it into three different columns (Country, State, and City). However, the number of repeated delimiters can vary. Sometimes it might just be USA > California and other times it may be USA > California > Los Angeles > Compton.

I want to take this column in one table

[          Location            ]

[USA > California > Los Angeles]

and insert three columns it into a different table

[Country ]      [State      ]       [City         ]

[USA     ]      [California ]       [Los Angeles  ]

So far, I have been able to get around only by using queries and not functions/more advanced techniques. If there's any way to keep this simple and as a query, I'd really appreciate any insight! Again, I use PL/SQL developer so I know that limits certain functions I am able to use.

Answer (score 0):

not too nice but should work for you:

```
insert into <your table 2> (Country, State, City)
    select trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Location, '^([^>])*')),
           trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Location, '>([^>])*'), '>', '')),
           trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Location, '>([^>])*', 1, 2), '>', ''))
      from <your table 1>;
```

Regards